# Generating Flat file output in specific order using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, if-statement, xslt, foreach

I am trying to convert XML to a flat file. The XML input is:

```
<PartsPriceListLine>
    <PartsProductItem>
        <ItemID>1234</ItemID>
        <PartName>abcd</PartName>
        <PartItemDescription>test</PartItemDescription>
    </PartsProductItem>
    <Price>
        <PriceCode>List</PriceCode>
        <ChargeAmount>544.04</ChargeAmount>
    </Price>
    <Price>
        <PriceCode>TradeIn</PriceCode>
        <ChargeAmount>489.64</ChargeAmount>
    </Price>
    <Price>
        <PriceCode>Sold</PriceCode>
        <ChargeAmount>408.03</ChargeAmount>
    </Price>
</PartsPriceListLine>
```

The PriceCode values could come in any order, however, the output file should always have a value of ChargeAmount assigned to a DailyPrice column when PriceCode value is 'Sold', to TradePrice Column when PriceCode value is 'TradeIn' and to ListPrice column when PriceCode value is 'List'.

I have written XSLT as below:

```html
          <xsl:for-each select="s2:PartsPriceListLine/s2:Price">
            <xsl:variable name="PriceCode" select="string(s2:PriceCode/text())"/>
   <xsl:variable name="ChargeAmount" select="string(s2:ChargeAmount/text())"/>
   
            <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test = "$PriceCode = 'Sold'">
   <DAILY_PRICE>
   
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($ChargeAmount,',')" />
            </DAILY_PRICE>
   </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test = "$PriceCode = 'Trade-In'">
   <TRADE_PRICE>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($ChargeAmount,',')" />
            </TRADE_PRICE>
   </xsl:when> 
   </xsl:choose>
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test = "$PriceCode = 'List'">
   <LIST_PRICE>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($ChargeAmount,',')" />
            </LIST_PRICE>
   </xsl:when> 
   </xsl:choose> 
     </xsl:for-each>
```

With above code, the values are being entered in output in the order they are mentioned in XML input file.

The output for above XSLT is:

> DAILY_PRICE,TRADE_PRICE,LIST_PRICE
>
> 544.04,489.64,408.03

whereas expected result is:

> DAILY_PRICE,TRADE_PRICE,LIST_PRICE
>
> 408.03,489.64,544.04

Please note the output doesn't require any Header/column names.

Any pointer/help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="PartsPriceListLine">
    <xsl:value-of select="Price[PriceCode='Sold']/ChargeAmount" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Price[PriceCode='TradeIn']/ChargeAmount" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Price[PriceCode='List']/ChargeAmount" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I managed to accomplish the task with a slightly different code. I applied for each loop for each of the nodes and then used xsl if to check the conditions. Your comment was helpful.